# When adding bordered links, the second link's border appears individually 2 other times

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation

[image: Here's a picture.]

Alright, so the problem is that I wanted two bordered links, but as you can see, there are two extra borders in there which seem to belong to the bookings link, although by looking into the code I did not make the mistake to type the link twice.

EDIT:
added another picture in case my explanation wasn't clear enough. It's the rectangles I'm pointing at that I want to get rid of

[image]

I'm sure there's a problem with the divs, but everything I've tried failed.

HTML:

```
        <div class="buttons">
        <div class="button1">
            <a href="explore.html">EXPLORE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="button2">
            <a href="booking.html">BOOKINGS</a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.button1 {
padding: 0 0 29px 50px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 0 0 29px 0px;
display: inline-block;
float:left;}

.button2 {
padding: 0 0 29px 0px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 0 0 29px 0px;
display: inline-block;}
.buttons a {
background-color: ffaaaa;
color: #832430;
border: 2px solid #832430;
padding: 14px 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;}
.buttons a:hover{
background-color: #832430;
color: white;
padding: 14px 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;}
```

Comment: this doesn't look like your screenshot? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmjgaV

Comment: so then the problem must be from the rest of the code, and not from the button divs?

Comment: I don't know. It's up to you to provide the minimal amount of code needed to replicate the issue you're trying to solve. See how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

here is your code fixed.

- do not repeat yourself, if you have the same properties for different elements use a class.
- you were missing a `#` in a property `background`

```css
.btn {
  padding: 0 0 29px 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 0 29px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.buttons a {
  background-color: #faa;
  color: #832430;
  border: 2px solid #832430;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display:block
}

.buttons a:hover {
  background-color: #832430;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="button1 btn">
    <a href="explore.html">EXPLORE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button2 btn">
    <a href="booking.html">BOOKINGS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice catch, thanks for the edit. it's not solved my problem though but i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the details from what you would like to do so I'll have to update it later.
Option 1: Quick way if you just want double border is to use border and box-shadow.
Option 2: More simple approach for this things is to use ::after selector, research it, your life will be a lot easier, :)!

```css
.buttons a {
    background-color: ffaaaa;
    color: #832430;
    border: 2px solid #832430;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px silver; /* one line of code for 2nd border */
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.buttons a:hover{
    background-color: #832430;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <a class="button" href="explore.html">EXPLORE</a>
  <a class="button" href="booking.html">BOOKINGS</a>
</div>
```

::after selector way

```css
.buttons .button-wrap{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.buttons a {
    background-color: ffaaaa;
    color: #832430;
    border: 2px solid #832430;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.buttons a:hover{
    background-color: #832430;
    color: white;
}

.buttons a::after{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 2px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="button-wrap">
      <a class="button" href="explore.html">EXPLORE</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrap">
      <a class="button" href="booking.html">BOOKINGS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But sorry, I think I didn't explain my issue properly. If you look at the picture I attached, there's the main links (explore + bookings) & then there's the two rectangles that are just kind of there, with no text inside them. Clicking on them takes me to the same page as the bookings link